# Spring Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration

I was trying to run a sample Spring application but I am fail to configure it. I searched my problem but every thing seem fine to me.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring Hello World</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Controller file in com.fyp.ptma.controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hi(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) {
        String message = "Hi " + name + "!";
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "hi";
    }

}
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fyp.ptma.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

hello.jsp in WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

<hr/>

    <form action="hi">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

ptma.xml file in tomcat at conf/Catalina/localhost/ptma.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context docBase="/Volumes/DataDrive/FYP/TestMonkeyAppWeb‬/WebContent‬‪" debug="0" crossContext="true" reloadable="true" >   
</Context>
```

I access my project as localhost:8080/ptma/
but it says HTTP Status 404 and tomcat log seem to work fine.

Comment: your form has no method attribute in it.

Comment: form attribute concern with some thing when i submit form, my problem is my page even wont open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welcome file mapping in your web.xml seems incorrect. Change it to something like index.jsp, create a file with this name in the root of your app and redirect to your fist controller.

Comment: i have index.jsp file at my webcontent/index.jsp, but files inside webcontent/WEB-INF/hello.jsp, wont open when i browse localhost:8080/ptma/hello it says HTTP status 404

Comment: Yes you have mapped jsp views to "/WEB-INF/views/" so they need to be stored in that directory.

Comment: and at tomcat log it prints  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ptma/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'

Comment: Can you please check if your controller is detected by annotation scan at startup?

Comment: thats the problem how i can detect it ?

Comment: Check if the package is correct (component scan), write a constructor into your controller and print a message. Also check the [default-servlet-handler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) section.

Comment: when i added System.out.print in default constructor of my Controller and ran tomcat and request  and requested my page, still same behaviour and my message was not printed on tomcat log

Comment: Please add <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> to spring-context.xml.

Comment: after adding above line when i access my page it prints this error org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:default-servlet-handler'.

Comment: Do you have spring-web.jar and spring-webmvc.jar in the classpath?

Comment: ok i changed my library from version 3.0 to 3.1 now that error is gone  but still unable to access that page. and there is no error printed in log

Comment: Yoiu need spring-aop.jar, aopalliance.jar and spring-beans.jar as well can you check that?